# Playing a sound when dropping an object Android

Tags: android, media-player, audio

I'm trying to make it so that when i drop and object onto a text view a i thought it would work similar to how i had it set up before only just activated differently. here is the way i'm setting it up.

```
MediaPlayer mysound;
TextView target =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.task1);
target.setOnDragListener(dragListener);

OnDragListener dragListener = new OnDragListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event)
    {
            int dragEvent = event.getAction();
            //TextView dropText = (TextView) v;

            switch(dragEvent)
            {
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:

                break;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                    break;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                    mysound=MediaPlayer.create(Quiz.this, R.raw.error );
                    mysound.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mysound) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            mysound.release();
                        }

                    });   
                    mysound.start();
                    break;
            }

            return true;
    }
};
```

log cat

> 03-12 22:49:50.799: D/MediaPlayer(10720): start() mUri is URL suppressed
>     03-12 22:49:50.809: I/ViewRootImpl(10720): Reporting drop result: true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since its a short sound just load it into memory using a sound pool. This way you have very quick access to the sound.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.SoundPool;
import android.media.SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.DragEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnDragListener;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnDragListener {


boolean loaded=false;
SoundPool soundPool;
int soundID;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); // here use the file name that task1 textview is contained in
    soundPool = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);

     soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId,
                    int status) {
                loaded = true;
            }
        });
        soundID = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.error, 1);


        TextView target =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.task1);
        target.setOnDragListener(this);


       }

@Override
public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
    int dragEvent = event.getAction();
    //TextView dropText = (TextView) v;

    switch(dragEvent)
    {
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:

        break;

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
            break;

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
         if (loaded) {
              AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
              float actualVolume = (float) audioManager
                      .getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
              float maxVolume = (float) audioManager
                      .getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
              float volume = actualVolume / maxVolume;

        soundPool.play(soundID, volume, volume, 1, 0, 1f);
        Log.e("Test", "Played sound");
    }
            break;
    }

    return true;
```

}
    }

Comment: where do i initialize the sound pool?

Comment: when i set up the sound pool it keeps giving me errors. i'm not sure why but it seying there is a syntax error on this line "soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new OnLoadCompleteListener() "

Comment: i edited my answer. you can just copy that class into yours and change the setoncontentview paramter to your xml file name.  Im not sure what your dragging into the textview so thats all i could do.

Comment: thats seems to work but i dont hear the sound playing. the log cat is telling it the sound played but i dont hear it

Comment: seems odd i just ran it on mine and i heard the sound after i turned the volume up. is your sound file in the raw folder ?

Comment: volume is at max on my phone but i cant hear the noise

Comment: where is your audio file located and is it a mp3 ? Are you trying to stream a file off the net or do you have it copied to your raw folder ?

Comment: its in the raw folder. its a .wav but i have used it within the same app and it plays

Comment: ok so i have tested the other instances where the sound did play it seems like somethign wrong with my phone but i'm not sure what

Comment: before you go can i put an If loop around the code you gave. i'm trying to make different sounds happen depending on which button is dragged?

Comment: if you want to add conditions to a play different sounds then load a few sound pools, so each one would have its own soundID.  Or you could make an hashmap of soundIDs etc.  Remember we are assuming that the sound files are small.  Large files your better using a mediaPlayer.

Comment: yeah the sound files are small there are about 3 seconds long at most. but i do get what yours saying